# clear cell content when value of another cell on another sheet changed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have want to clear the result of a combobox  selection on sheet1 (A1) by changing the value of F4 on sheet2 (this change by another combobox in sheet 1).
I use the following code on sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("sheet2!F4")) Is Nothing Then

Range("A1").ClearContents

End If

End Sub
```

THE PROBLEM IS, if the changed cell (F4) is empty, entering or changing any value will work (clear A1 on sheet1), but if the change become from another cell (for eg if in F4 you type =D4) target cell (A1) will not clear by changing the values.
Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

Paste the below code in Sheet2 because that's where the change is occuring.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'On Cell Calculate
    Dim target1 As Range
    Set target1 = Range("F4")

    If Not Intersect(target1, target1) Is Nothing Then
        Call ClearBox
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    'On Cell Change
    If target.Address = "$F$4" Then
        Call ClearBox
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ClearBox()
    'Clear Combo box
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. The change event only gets triggered when a cell is edited, not when a formula recalculates and the cell value changes. If you have a formula in F4, then you will need to monitor the cells that contribute to that formula. In this case, if F4 contains the formula `=D4`, you will need to monitor D4 for changes in the change event.